# Difference between eval and vis stages in Deeplab v3+

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is the `eval.py` essentially just performing the same predictions as `vis.py` would, and then calculating the performance of the predictions as well? I am wondering because I have been playing with some settings in `eval` to optimize the `mIoU`, and I assume that if I give these same parameters to the `vis.py` script then the quality in the segmentation images from `vis.py` will also improve?